Was the tree of life the reward for Adam and Eve if they passed the test of not eating from the tree of knowledge of good and evil?
Drawing a parallel to the test given to Christians by God, could it be that access to the tree of life was going to be granted to Adam and Eve if they passed that test.



Adam and Eve
Christians




Test was to resist eating from the tree of knowledge of good and evil
Test is to have faith in the Son of God


A serpent tricked them to eat from that tree
An ancient serpent makes war on all Christians who keep the commandments of God


There was a tree in that garden called the tree of life, though access was blocked after they sinned
Jesus grants access to a tree of life which is in the paradise of God



Since the devil acted independently to cause the fall of Adam and Eve then it can be conluded that God was against this scheme by the devil which raises the question, was the tree of life there as a rewad if Adam and Eve stood by what God commanded them?
Genesis 3:22

And the LORD God said, Behold, the man is become as one of us, to know good and evil: and now, lest he put forth his hand, and take also of the tree of life, and eat, and live for ever


Has the main Q omitted the vital word 'not' at , "...passed the test of NOT eating from..."? I ask because there is one school of faith that maintains they were supposed to eat of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil. But if you do not hold that view, then 'not' should be added to your Q, at that point.

@Anne, God is partaker of no evil, the Bible has stated numerous times that God and Baal do not eat from the same table, this was an act of rebellion against God and his creation. The same rebellion that was orchestrated in heaven was being initiated here on earth, God is light, he is always thinking and planning good things for his creation, to try and imagine that he meant for Adam and Eve to break a command he personally gave them is out of the question.

Noting those points, then, the phrase in your question should read”…’passed the test of not eating…’ Yes?

@Anne, sure editing the title of the post.

Where did you get the idea that it was a test?

@CandidMoe, why did God create the tree of knowledge of good and evil and placed it in the garden if it was not a test?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany. (Gen 2:9, 3:6) Because God likes to eat his fruits and wanted for him, not for Adam, who was created for the sole purpose of growing his food (Gen 2:11) and make a pleasant place for him (Gen 3:8).

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Second, If it were a test, it means that God cannot predict the future or its alternatives (God is not omniscient). If He must place a prohibition, it means that He created man imperfect, because He made him capable of disobedience (God is not perfect).

@CandidMoe, God created that tree and still placed it in the garden with a purpose, he was going to use it to test them and if they passed then he would grant access to the tree of life.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Pure speculation without any quote from the bible.

@CandidMoe, why would God create a tree and place it in a garden and then order his creatures not to eat from it, why is God even placing that tree in the garden in the first place? It was a test, God gives you the law and tests you, God tests but the devil tempts , its different.

@CandidMoe  Noting your comments, I suggest reading this free download would be helpful:  Knowledge and Life, Nigel Johnstone, (Belmont Publications 2013) http://www.belmontpublications.co.uk

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Noting your comments, I suggest reading this free download would be helpful:  Knowledge and Life, Nigel Johnstone,  (Belmont Publications 2013) http://www.belmontpublications.co.uk

@Anne, nice try, a publication by Nigel? I read one of his answers yesterday that suggested that it is possible to know if you will inherit eternal life, you can only hope and not know

@SoFewAgainstSoMany  You may disagree with the author in that Q he answered (on a different topic) but that should not stop you reading his full biblical exposition on the trees in the Garden, in that book (112 pages). After all, if we only read expositions with which we already agree, we will not face up to issues we may not have noticed before. Peace.

The answer depends on (1) getting the biblical understanding of what the tree of life represented. It is also important to recognise that, (2) because God knew before creating anything material that one of his spirit sons would try to wrest sovereignty over the Earth from its creator, he declared in Eden how to counteract this; so, to partake of life was to hear, believe, and obey his revealed will.
(1)  No fruit from any tree on earth can give anyone eternal life. Likewise, there is no fruit from any tree on earth that can give knowledge of any kind to anyone. Whatever Genesis means regarding the two Genesis trees, they are symbolic in application. After the Genesis opening accounts, the only one of those trees that is ever mentioned again in the Bible is the Tree of Life, which is no longer on earth, but in heaven. It is mentioned in conjunction with the river of the water of life - see Revelation 21:1-5. But the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil is no more mentioned after the end of Genesis chapter 4.
Here is an extract from a book that deals with this point - the first point of importance being to know what this 'knowledge of good and evil' is that warned of by God, in the opening chapters of Genesis.

"The tree of the knowledge of good and evil is not food. 'Thou dost not eat of it' says the literal Hebrew [Young] Gen. 2:17. Thou dost not eat of that because it is not edible! 'In the very day that thou eatest thereof, thou shalt die' because you can't digest it!
...Life needs to be initiated, increased and sustained by the Tree of
Life. And that Tree is in the very midst of the garden. "Of the trees
of the garden thou mayest freely eat". These very words are the Tree
of Life. The Word. The Word which was from the beginning. Eat that
word. First. Eat it and imbibe it and understand that thou art to eat
to live. Thou are to eat of that which is freely given - to live. Turn
away from that, and you die...
For God is a Spirit. And can only be approached and worshipped in
Spirit. He cannot be approached by that which is natural and of
creation. It is not possible. To attempt it, is to die. But word is
required. Yet not the word that is mere knowledge. Not the various
trees that came out of the ground, in the garden though they be. And
not, absolutely not, that word of mere knowledge that pertains to good
and evil. Which presupposes the presence of life capable of performing
that which is required.
The first utterance of the word of God shows how utterly essential it
is for us to understand this primary concept. And this is what
repentance is about, above all. Having another mind about this very
matter. Else, we cannot progress to anything else. Hear. Eat. Live."
Knowledge and Life, Nigel Johnstone, pp 17-19 (Belmont Publications 2013) http://www.belmontpublications.co.uk

That quote is designed to show that until we grasp what the Tree of Life is, we will never understand what the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil is. Everyone gets waylaid with thoughts of apples and fig-leaves. But it is not about literal objects made out of matter. Discover the meaning of the Tree of Life first, and then it can be partaken of, as described in the last book of the Bible, Revelation, when God has brought to pass the new creation, and the new humanity.
(2)  Now, the command of God in Eden that shows how he imparted knowledge as to what the tree of life really was, and that to partake of it was to hear, believe, and obey his revealed will. More from the same book:

"Having made the man and having made all necessary provision for the
man, God 'commanded' him. The word here is tsavah, not the word used
in connection with the ten commandments which are called dabar... I
would say that the word translated 'command' in Genesis 1:16,
tsavah, is a matter of what is right. A matter of rightness. It is not a matter of what to do, in order to live. It is about how to
live. It is not a rule about what to do about living. It is the
way in which to live. The right way to live.
And, firstly, Genesis 2:16, God tells Adam, Of every tree of the
garden eating thou dost eat. Young's Literal. Every tree. Which
includes the Tree of Life. Eating, thou dost eat. Then, secondly,
Genesis 2:17, and of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou
dost not eat of it, for in the day of thine eating of it, dying thou
dost die. Young's Literal again.
These are the first words of God to man. Here, in the beginning, he
spoke. Which means that he revealed himself. He revealed himself in
word. In speech. In utterance. This is how he reveals himself. In the
beginning was the Word.
And this is how to live. Eat of that which is of God - and eating thou
shalt eat. It is a Tree of Life. ...But thou dost not eat of the other
tree. This is not, really, a command. It is a statement of fact.
Thou dost not eat of that. It is not food!
This is not, as some men try to make out, the giving of some kind of
law to Adam...
Instructing Adam to eat what is proper, God, by his very word, reveals
the Tree of Life. God is stating to Adam what is necessary for his
life. And God is telling Adam what is harmful to that life. And, in so
doing, God has revealed himself, in word. A certain kind of word.
Tsavah. The stone tables, the ten sayings, are another form of word. Dabar.
Tsavah. Begins with Tzaddi. Tsavah is the word of righteousness. Dabar is the law, the word that says, This do and thou shalt live. Tsavah says eat and thou shalt live. Dabar says this do, and thou shalt live.
...As to what is of spirit, God is a spirit, also, eat. Receive,
freely, what is of God. Engage with it; experience it; digest it; be
one with it.... In the beginning was the word. Logos. He, in whom was
Life. He was there, all the time. Revealed. The Word." (Ibid pages
25-28)

Much more could be said, especially about the correct translation of Genesis 3:22, but space does not permit. Already this answer has become very long, but it is necessary to show that Adam was already 'partaking' of the Tree of Life - the Word of Life - for God had given him life and was sustaining his life - up until Adam decided he would turn to another source for life as 'a god'. He then 'partook' of a lie as his chosen source of knowledge. And all it did was reveal to him that he was naked. Yet God knew there was no need for Adam to be clothed, therefore no clothes were provided for him - until he partook of the 'bad fruit' that brings death. It certainly looked good, and desirable, until partaken of. But God already has the Tree of Life in heaven. Will we hear his word about that and be partakers of that, for life everlasting?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany  My answer points to God, who spoke living words of life to Adam, as that Tree of Life. God was "in the midst of the garden" (as were all the literal  trees). Once sin entered into God's good garden, Adam was not welcome. He had rebelled against God's words and sought knowledge from a deceptive source, so was sent away from the source of Life eternal, with no way back via human wisdom or efforts - hence the symbolic language of cherubim and a flaming sword.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany  The whole account is an intriguing mix of literal and symbolic. I won't go into angelology here, however. That is another matter, another question.

No. The tree of the life was already open to them before. It says, "every tree of the garden thou mayest freely eat," as the tree of life is not included in the negative statement following, it would be among the other trees of the garden that were allowed.

“And the LORD God commanded the man, saying, Of every tree of the garden thou mayest freely eat: But of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou shalt not eat of it: for in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die.”
(Gen. 2:16-17 KJV)

It was only after they sinned that the tree of life was forbidden to them.

But had they eaten of it because scripture is explicit that if they ate of that tree they would live forever?

Short answer to that is we don't know. The Bible doesn't say. It could be that eating the fruit of knowledge negated the tree of life "in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die,” but they could very will have just not eaten of it, either because they weren't in the garden long (we don't know how long they were there either), or because they never got around to it yet.

just it was there so maybe God placed it in a hidden area so he could d test them first

@SoFewAgainstSoMany  Revelation 22:2 says the tree of life bears fruit every month.  It is unlikely that one taste gives eternal life but, rather, that access to the tree so that it may be eaten of continually grants life.  Thus this answer is correct.

@MikeBorden, did you read what the Lord God said? He said if they allowed Adam and Eve to have a single bite, it would allow them to live forever.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Where exactly does the Scripture indicate a "single bite"?

@MikeBorden, why does God order a sword that turns in all directions to guard the way to the tree of life? While they might have had access to this tree before, they were deemed unworthy olf eating from it after they sinned.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany "And the LORD God said, Behold, the man is become as one of us, to know good and evil: and now, lest he put forth his hand, and take also of the tree of life, and eat, and live for ever".

@MikeBorden, there you have your answer . Lest they reach out and eat from the tree of life and eat and live for ever,  means they have never eaten from this tree before

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Not necessarily so.  You are assuming that one bite grants eternal life but the scripture does not say that.

How appropriate for this question to pop up during Christmas season!

Some troparia (hymns) of the Christmas feast say that Christ, through His incarnation, is the tree of life. The dismissal hymn of the forefeast of Christmas is characteristic: It says: "Make Bethlehem ready, Edom has opened to all, prepare Ephratha, now in the cave the tree of life has blossomed from the Virgin. And Paradise, that womb in which the divine plant, to eat of which we shall not die like Adam, has been made known. Christ is born, resurrecting the image which had previously fallen". (Saint Andrew Greek Orthodox Church)

Christians throughout the centuries have understood the Cross of our Lord Jesus Christ to be the Tree of Life restored again to all of humanity. Here is a beautiful quote

“Under the Old Covenant the Tree of Life continued to remain hidden from humanity, and it was only with the Crucifixion that it was finally made manifest. Greatly saddened was the Tree of Life when it beheld Adam stolen away from it. It sank down into the virgin ground and was hidden; to burst forth and reappear on Golgotha.” (Saint Ephrem: Hymn on Virginity XVI)

What is this “fruit” that hung from the Cross? It is Jesus and here is His invitation to us:

“Then Jesus said to them, “Most assuredly, I say to you, unless you eat the flesh of the Son of Man and drink His blood, you have no life in you. Whoever eats My flesh and drinks My blood has eternal life, and I will raise him up at the last day. For My flesh is food indeed, and My blood is drink indeed. He who eats My flesh and drinks My blood abides in Me, and I in him” (John 6:53-56).

Saint Maximus the Confessor appeals to the hymnography of our Church in which the Cross is often referred to as the Tree of Life and he compares the “two trees” – the Tree of Knowledge and the Tree of Life. Accordingly, the Tree of Life – the Cross – is the Sign of God’s Love. The Tree of Knowledge of good and evil is the symbol of deception, by which we arrogantly seek “worldly pleasures” (as good) that are always beyond our reach, thereby causing grief (which is evil). The Tree of Knowledge provides knowledge for satisfying our bodily passions, as worship of “self.” The Tree of Life provides knowledge of God and the wisdom to maintain loving relationships in worship of Christ. (Based on the Philokalia, Vol. 2, “Second Century on Theology,” by St. Maximos the Confessor, pg. 145)

A little detail on the understanding of paradise.
The Old Testament preserves some indication of the blessed life of Adam and Eve in Paradise. According to the teaching of the Holy Fathers, Paradise was intelligible and tangible. It was intelligible because it was man's communion with God, for after his creation Adam's nous was in a state of illumination, and by God's energy and his won synergy he should have attained deification (theosis). It was tangible as well, because it was a specific place.
So there are two special trees in paradise with unique meaning and purpose, the tree of knowledge of good and evil, and the tree of life. humanity ate and died from one. And they didn't get to eat from the other tree, so they wouldn't be trapped in the state of the fall, enduring this evil state forever.
So there we see God's love for mankind. He expels man from Paradise so that he will not remain immortal forever. (Think of the verse where we are told to not sin so that "grace may abound!")  Humanity can repent and at the suitable time, through the Incarnation of the Son of God, may taste of the tree of life and overcome death and enter paradise again.
So then man's expulsion from paradise was not a punishment by God, but an act of His love and philanthropy.

Saint John of Damascus writes that the tree of knowledge is a test, a trial and a school, to test man for obedience or disobedience. This tree was called the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, because it gave to anyone who ate of it the power to know its nature, a thing that is good for the perfect and bad for the imperfect and those who lack control over their sensation. The tree of life is so called because it has an energy which provides life either for those worthy of life or for those not enslaved to death.
This interpretation of Saint John of Damascus shows that man had to be tested before eating of the tree of knowledge and then to eat of the tree of life and live eternally with God. Without practice and preparation it is not possible for anyone to attain deification (theosis) and communion with God.

From the perspective of the narrative, Adam and Eve already had access to the tree of life at the center of the garden; they were permitted to eat from any tree except that of the tree of knowledge.
However, viewing things metaphorically, yes: the tree of life was their reward if they had obeyed God.
Note that there are strong parallels between the story of Adam & Eve and Deuteronomy 30:15-20. In both cases a choice is presented between life and death, between loving the LORD and obeying his commandments or being led astray and serving other gods (the serpent). Obedience also let's them stay in the promised land whereas disobedience leads to their exile from it. The land of Israel is essentially presented as a second Eden in the Pentateuch.
The Law is also like the tree of knowledge of good and evil. Just as eating the fruit brought Adam & Eve guilt and shame, so too does the Law make us aware of our sins and bring us guilt and shame that makes us hide from God's presence. This idea of hiding from God comes up again and again in scripture. For example: Moses wore a veil to hide his face because it glowed after being in God's presence - and the people feared him.

“See, I have placed before you today life and happiness, and death and adversity, 16 in that I am commanding you today to love the Lord your God, to walk in His ways and to keep His commandments, His statutes, and His judgments, so that you may live and become numerous, and that the Lord your God may bless you in the land where you are entering to take possession of it. 17 But if your heart turns away and you will not obey, but allow yourself to be led astray and you worship other gods and serve them, 18 I declare to you today that you will certainly perish. You will not prolong your days in the land where you are crossing the Jordan to enter and take possession of it. 19 I call heaven and earth to witness against you today, that I have placed before you life and death, the blessing and the curse. So choose life in order that you may live, you and your descendants, 20 by loving the Lord your God, by obeying His voice, and by holding close to Him; for this is your life and the length of your days, [aa]so that you may live in the land which the Lord swore to your fathers, to Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob, to give them.”


How could "The land of Israel [be] essentially presented as a second Eden" when filled with sinners? Eden closed down once sin entered in due to trying to do that which was not for them (becoming 'as God'). You then contradict your first point with: "the Law make[s] us aware of our sins and bring us guilt and shame that makes us hide from God's presence." So, the land of Israel shows the impossibility of sinners getting rid of their guilt and shame by law-keeping, as they could never keep God's perfect law. It condemned them. A&E were condemned by doing a turning from God's free word of life.

@Anne The Garden was a paradise, bountiful in food, and where God walked with man. Israel is the promised land, overflowing with milk and honey, and is a land where God is said to reside. In both Eden and Israel, to love and obey the Lord leads to life while to disobey and to go and serve others leads to death and exile. Now, obviously Israel is not Eden itself - however, the parallels are clear. Nor do the parallels between Genesis and the rest of the Pentateuch cease there; but there is not enough room in the comments to explore the matter. Suffice to say Eden is a type for Israel.

This is a false teaching, the garden of Eden is not the promised land.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany I didn’t say it was…

Genesis 3:6 says that the forbidden fruit was good for food and pleasing to the eye. It is possible that the Fruit of Tree of Life ( Well, not of Everlasting Life) was not tasty or pleasing to the eye, because of which Eve and Adam did not eat it.
Had they first eaten of the Fruit of Life, the Fruit of death would have annulled its effect. Now that they have discerned between the Fruit of Death and the Fruit of Life( Gen 3:22)  they would not go back to the former after accessing the latter.Hence the chance of their living forever.

I bet to differ, if they are of that fruit, they would have lived forever, that's what Gen 3:22 says, how is the tree of life in the garden any different from the one Jesus promised Christians?

I am only trying to explain why God speaks of the prospects their living ' forever' and how they were destined to die in spite of the Tree of Life having already been there.  Perhaps, you have looked at the Tree of Life  as Tree of Everlasting Life. Hence the clarification.

its presence in the garden was not a co-incidence though? it was placed there for a reason.

Let me draw up an imaginary picture : They first eat of the Tree of Life and get life - they then eat of Tree of Death and  earn death - then they run to Tree of Life and live again - Now they are wiser and vow never to go near the Tree of Death again.

but the immediate effect of eating from that tree was living forever, God says it as if even a single bite would have made them eternal

If you want to be convinced, please ask yourself ; How come Adam lived on till the age of 930 years ? And: Why were the trees not named after Everlasting Death and Everlasting Life ?

Your point is valid brother, the generations before Noah lived a couple of centuries because sin had not yet increased in the face of the earth
